# jQuery - Masonry showing no error yet not working?

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-masonry

I've been trying for over 7 hours to get the layout sorted, im wanting the end product to look something along these lines - ![image: want it to look like]

instead i get this ![image: currently looks like]

Heres the code thats being used

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<head>

<title>_Box</title>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="masonry.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    columnWidth: 150,
    itemSelector: 'div' 
    });
});
</script>

<div id="container" class="clearfix masonry">

<div class="item1"><img src="images/eventbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item3"><img src="images/forumbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item2"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item2"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item2"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item2"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item3"><img src="images/top10box.png"></img></div>
<div class="item1"><img src="images/eventbox.png"></img></div>

</div>

</head>
</body>
```

CSS -

```
html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  width:900px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:100px;
  background-image: url(images/gridbg.png);
}

#container {
    width:900px;
}

.item1,.item2,.item3 {margin:5px;}
.item1 {width:350px;}
.item2 {width:175px;}
.item3 {width:150px;}
```

Any ideas? because it seems nothing will work

Comment: `$('#container').masonry({
    columnWidth: 150,
    itemSelector: 'div'
  });`

Comment: @Jashwant Remove the last comma or older versions of IE will throw an error

Comment: that was a typo. I never do that, not even in php :)

Comment: Anyone else got any ideas? Nothing seems to work!

Comment: Your head tag closes at a weird place even though I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Ah yea, thanks though like you guessed thats not fixed anything

Comment: I've made a [small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dozoisch/ctjh7/), and am trying to tweak it around. If you want to put the size of your images on the divs (in the fiddle) and add it to your question (after re saving it with the good sizes)!

Comment: @HugoDozois You beautiful man! haha finally fixed - copy that code as answer and i'll accept yours and +rep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dozoisch/ctjh7/) that I made.

I've noticed that by putting low columns width number it improves the way the Masonry works.

So I modified the Scrip to something like that :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').masonry({
        columnWidth: 1,
        itemSelector: 'div'
    });
});
```

Also, adding fixed weight/height might help. Especially for handling margins around the item because masonry seems to have some problems with the margins between elements.

So if your big items is 350px be sure that items that go under are not more than `(350 -(2*margin)) /2`px so it places them properly.